# 404 retrieving Twitter followers using JQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, jsonp

I'm just starting to use the Twitter API to retrieve data using jQuery.  I've used the API ok to retrieve information about a single user e.g. https://twitter.com/users/show/codinghorror.json

When I try to retrieve all the users that a given user is following, I'm using the same retrieval pattern but am getting a 404 error (it looks like my callback isn't receiving the json object properly, but appending it to the URL somehow)

I'm using the following code:

```
getTwitterUserFriends: function() {
            var user = 'codinghorror';
            var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?screen_name='+user+'?callback=?';
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                alert('call succeeded' + data.ids);
            });
        },
```

In chrome, the console shows the following error:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=codinghorror?callback=jQuery15201747908447869122_1324917568956&_=1324917580929 404 (Not Found)
```

However if I browse to the URL directly https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=codinghorror then I can see the results object being returned.

I assume I'm doing something simple wrong with my callback, but can't see what it is, as the approach I've used above has worked for other API calls, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL syntax is incorrect.  The "callback" parameter should be separated by "&", not "?".

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?&screen_name='+user+'&callback=?';
```

You should probably URL-encode the username too:

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?&screen_name=' +
  escapeURIComponent(user) + 
  '&callback=?';
```

Also I'm not sure why you've got a "&" before the "screen_name" parameter.

Comment: I've been following the following example which uses ?callback to invoke jquery JSONP behaviour: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/13/interactive-google-map/

Comment: Agree on url-encoding, missed it out for simplicity here

Comment: Swapped to &callback and it worked tho, thanks.  Must have overlooked something when reading the example....

Comment: ah, just a brain bypass day.  Other examples the callback is the only parameter in the query string, hence ? not &.  I had assumed there was some significance to using ? in this case

Comment: I can accept answer in 5 mins apparently.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a note: If you are using jQuery and the callback variable is called `callback` you don't need to set it: `var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?&screen_name='+user`

Comment: have you ever handled the error in your code ? are you able to trap the errors ? 404 etc ?